# if no respeta la condición

Tags: php5

Estoy intentando hacer un carrito de compras para el pago de cuotas y no quiero que se duplique una cuota que ya esta cargada en la sesión del carrito. Intento hacerlo con `if/else` pero no da resultado, es como no me tomara los datos que comparo.

A ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
<?php
    //action.php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["action"])) {
        if($_POST["action"] == "add") {
            $product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
            $product_name = $_POST["product_name"];
            $product_price = $_POST["product_price"];
            for($count = 0; $count < count($product_id); $count++) {
                $cart_product_id = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                $item_array = array(
                'product_id'               =>     $product_id[$count],  
                'product_name'             =>     $product_name[$count],
                'product_price'            =>     $product_price[$count],
                'product_quantity'         =>     1
                );
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$product_id[$count]] = $item_array;
            }
        }
        $idProductos = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'],"product_id");
        if(in_array($product_id,$idProductos)) {
            echo"<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
            La Cuota seleccionada ya esta agregada al Carrito... No se permite pagar dos cuotas 
            iguales.</div>";
        } else {
            echo"
            <div class=\"alert alert-success mb-2 mt-0 pb-0 mb-0\">Items Agregado al Carrito. 
            </div>\n";  
        }
    }
?>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: debajo de la linea de `$idProductos=` haz un `print_r($idProductos);print_r($product_id);die();` y comparalos a ver que sucede

Comment: me da este resultado Array ( [0] => 200281 [1] => 200282 ) Array ( [0] => 200281 )

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto: `if(in_array($product_id,$idProductos)) {`? ¿No entra en ese `if`? ¿Verificaste lo que hay en ambas variables?

Comment: lo verifique y me da como resultado Array ( [0] => 200281 [1] => 200282 ) Array ( [0] => 200281 )

Comment: o sea que el valor 200281 se repite dos veces, no entiendo :(

Comment: @AlejandroArla no es eso, no se repite dos veces, son los valores de ambas variables, una seguida de la otra. Te lo habia pedido para saber que contenian esas variables y verificar que ocurria en ese punto. Mírate mi respuesta y lo entenderas.

Comment: @AlejandroArla una pregunta, no acabo de entender que es eso de la cuota y bajo que criterio quieres dar el aviso. `$product_id` en tu prueba tan solo contenia un elemento, y con mi respuesta pues vale, funciona, ¿pero que ocurre si contiene varios?  ¿deseas compararlos todos a la vez o uno a uno? Porque si es uno a uno entonces debes ejecutar otro `for` para recorrerlo de nuevo y dentro meter el `in_array`, y sin embargo, si son todos a la vez entonces la respuesta de @EdisondosSantos es más viable.

Comment: Me parece que lo esencial en tu caso es **clarificar el código**. Intento *adivinar* lo que pretendes hacer mareando tanto los datos que al final me pierdo ... ¿Esto es un array en el origen `$_POST["product_id"]`? Si lo es, ¿por qué lo es? Luego ... que si `array_keys`, que si `array_column`, que si `in_array`  ... ¿Por qué marear tanto los datos? A veces conviene alejarse un poco del código y replantear de nuevo el problema desde la sencillez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He identificado dos problemas en el script, el primero de ellos es la función [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) como ya lo habían mencionado previamente. No obstante, en este caso es preferible utilizar la función de [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect.php) que te muestra la intersección de arrays, la cual puedes combinar con la función [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) y te devuelve el número de intersecciones entre los arrays **$product_id** y **$idProductos**, de la siguiente manera:

```
if(count(array_intersect($product_id, $idProductos)) > 0) {
```

El segundo problema tiene que ver con la posición en la que estás realizando la comparación, es decir, primero registras la sesión y luego realizas la comparación, cuando debería ser al revés, lo cual hace que los valores se te repitan dos veces como habías mencionado previamente. Para esto ubicaremos el if antes del for, **$idProductos** antes del if para poder realizar la comparación, y el for estará ubicado dentro del else para asegurar que los items se agreguen tras comprobar que no hay duplicaciones. Pero antes de eso, nos aseguraremos de que la variable **$_SESSION['shopping_cart']** ya exista para evitar problemas con la variable **$idProductos**, de la siguiente manera:

```
$idProductos = isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) ? array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'],"product_id") : [];
```

Uniendo todo el código, queda lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    //action.php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["action"])) {
        if($_POST["action"] == "add") {
            $product_id = $_POST["product_id"];
            $product_name = $_POST["product_name"];
            $product_price = $_POST["product_price"];
            $idProductos = isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) ? array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'],"product_id") : [];
            if(count(array_intersect($product_id, $idProductos)) > 0) {
                echo"<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
                La Cuota seleccionada ya esta agregada al Carrito... No se permite pagar dos cuotas 
                iguales.</div>";
            } else {
                for($count = 0; $count < count($product_id); $count++) {
                    $cart_product_id = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                    $item_array = array(
                    'product_id'               =>     $product_id[$count],  
                    'product_name'             =>     $product_name[$count],
                    'product_price'            =>     $product_price[$count],
                    'product_quantity'         =>     1
                    );
                    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$product_id[$count]] = $item_array;
                }
                echo"
                <div class=\"alert alert-success mb-2 mt-0 pb-0 mb-0\">Items Agregado al Carrito. 
                </div>\n";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, se resolvió el problema, eres un genioooooooooo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el condicional siguiente:

```php
if(in_array($product_id,$idProductos)) {
```

Los datos que le estas pasando a la función son dos array, y tal como has contestado en los comentarios, ambas variables, en el momento de llegar a la función, tienen estos valores:

```php
$product_id = ["200281"];
$idProductos = ["200281","200282"];
```

La función **[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)** es capaz de buscar un array dentro de otro array, pero de forma exacta, es decir, como array y no como elemento de valor de array.

Lo explico mejor con un ejemplo. Si las variables hubieran sido así:

```php
$product_id = ["200281"];
$idProductos = [["200281"],["200282"]];
```

entonces sí lo hubiera encontrado, pues la variable `$idProductos` seria un array que contiene arrays, y no tan solo valores.

La solución es simple. Tan solo hemos de sacar el valor del array `$product_id` para hacer la búsqueda de valores dentro del array `$idProductos`, que tan solo contiene valores (y no arrays).

Por lo tanto, sustituye esa línea por esta:

```php
if(in_array($product_id[0],$idProductos)) {
```

y deberia funcionarte bien.

En este caso usamos la búsqueda con `in_array` de un valor (`$product_id[0]`) en un array de valores (`$idProductos`).

Espero que se me haya entendido.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las enseñanzas. Este foro es genial y lleno de gente con mucho conocimiento. Mil gracias.